# How to access iam-info associated with an instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am new to EC2 and am currently learning how to use it. I am currently trying hands-on IAM,S3 and EC2. This is the first time I am using IAM. I am trying to create a file in my directory which would contain meta-data and include hostname, iam-info and security groups. I was able to retrieve the instance host name and security groups. However, I am not able to retrieve iam-info. I tried using the following for retrieving the iam-info:

http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/iam/info

I want to used curl command to take the output and redirect it into the file in my directory.
However, I am using nginx too which interrupts the curl command execution and displayed an error. I went through the EC2 guide in AWS:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_iam-ec2.html

I went through the instance identity guide which I cannot copy here as this is my first question and I am allowed only 2 links.
The contents of metadata file should look as similar to this after execution:

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2016-04-05T16:45:21Z",
  "InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::234179547755:instance-profile/S3-access",
  "InstanceProfileId" : "AIPAIKSVFD6G6V26PMAGO"
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish. You shouldn't need to write the EC2 instance profile IAM information to a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct URL is:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info/
```

and this information is available **ONLY** if an IAM profile is attached to your instance, otherwise you will not see it.

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info/
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2017-10-06T16:36:38Z",
  "InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789:instance-profile/MyInstanceRole",
  "InstanceProfileId" : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
}
```

Do you see **iam** in the output of:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```